# Loopback and Express wiring

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I am planning to build a new application with express (for frontend) and loopback for managing all APIs, hosted on different servers.

How would you typically architect this, would the app (browser) directly make http requests to loopback for data, or would all requests go through expressjs and user never interacts with loopback?

If its the former, how do you do session management? If its latter, would you need to recreate all routes even in express?

Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am co-author and a core developer of LoopBack.*

LoopBack is using Express under the hood. Every LoopBack application is an Express application too, therefore you can use any Express compatible middleware (like session management) and define Express-based routes in your LoopBack project.

It's entirely possible to write a LoopBack application that's serving both REST/JSON API and front-end files, we have users successfully running this setup in production.

As for session management, I don't know what exactly are you asking about. In general, you handle sessions in LoopBack the same way you handle them in Express.

You may find the following resources helpful:

- [Defining middleware](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-middleware.html)
- [Use cookies securely](https://strongloop.github.io/strongloop.com/strongblog/best-practices-for-express-in-production-part-one-security/#use-cookies-securely)

Comment: By the way is the loopback designed to use with external frontend? At the moment I'm using express for frontend and loopback in backend as rest. Should I move my frontend code base to loopback?

Comment: We are not prescribing a single approach, both ways are fine. Use whatever works best for you!

Comment: hey @miroslav-bajtoš, can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271853/store-session-in-operation-hook-loopback