# Store session in operation hook - Loopback

Tags: session, loopbackjs, express-session, connect-mongo

I want to store some data other than `userId` or `accessToken` to store in a session, in `after save` or `before save` operation hook in Loopback application using `express-session`.

I have this in my `server/server.js` :

```
....
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
....

app.use(session({
    name:'session-name',
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: new MongoStore({url: 'mongodb://localhost/test', ttl:1}),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

And as I'm defining the remote-method with some parameters it actually passing the parameter and not the `req` object, so I can't do it the express way.

How can I use the session to store and get value?

**EDIT :**
I have found a way to set the session in remote method, by adding this to my model.json's remote-method :

```
"accepts": [
    {
        "arg": "req",
        "type": "object",
        "http": {
            "source": "req"
        }
    }
]
```

And, adding the `req` parameter to the remote-method function,

```
Model.remoteMethod = function (req, callback) {
    req.session.data = { 'foo': 'bar' }
    callback(null)
};
```

Now, the **issue** is I want to get this session value in operation hook

```
Model.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
    //How to get the session here?
})
```

Comment: what you have getting error and response. please explain

Comment: I don't know how to store data in session (other than access token or user id)

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but I would attach the whole context object (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html#http-mapping-of-input-arguments) to the instance in question with the remote hook and remove it in the `before save` hook afterwards. The problem is that the model hooks aren't necessarily associated with individual requests. This is something that they either have or are trying to solve in LoopBack 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this now](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-context) :

**you can set ctx value :**

```
var LoopBackContext = require('loopback-context');

    MyModel.myMethod = function(cb) {
      var ctx = LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext();
      // Get the current access token
      var accessToken = ctx && ctx.get('accessToken');
      ctx.set('xx', { x: 'xxxx' } );

    }
```

**it's get ctx value :**

```
 module.exports = function(MyModel) {
      MyModel.observe('access', function(ctx, next) {
        const token = ctx.options && ctx.options.accessToken;
        const userId = token && token.userId;
        const modelName = ctx.Model.modelName;
        const scope = ctx.where ? JSON.stringify(ctx.where) : '<all records>';
        console.log('%s: %s accessed %s:%s', new Date(), user, modelName, scope);
        next();
      });
    };
```

`loopback` context store `userId` and `accesTokan`. in whole web you can access using `ctx`  it's work like `session` in `loopback`.

Comment: hey, I tried this, but getting the stored object in ctx object undefined.

Comment: can you install loopback-context model..?

Comment: Yes, I installed it along with cls-hooked

Comment: can you add server/middleware.json    this code

{
  "initial": {
    "loopback-context#per-request": {
      "params": {
        "enableHttpContext": true
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: what's your loopback version..?

Comment: I am using  loopback version 3

Comment: I don't need accessToken or userId, I just want what I stored in ctx.

Comment: hey @imranali, Updated the question if you can help with this one.

Comment: I think that using loopback-context is dangerous... It's been a while since I triaged LB3 issues but I know that there were a lot of race conditions (sorry I can't give a better answer, but I don't want anyone to shoot themselves in the foot).